# Parametric form of curve $\vert z+i\vert = 1$

Tags: complex-integration

I need to integrate a complex function through the curve $\vert z+i\vert = 1$.
As far as I know I need the parametric form of this curve.
I know that when I have $\vert z\vert = 1$, the parametric form is something like $\cos(t) + i\sin(t)$.
But what's different when I have that "$+i$"?

Comment: You probably don't need a parametrisation, more likely Cauchy's integral theorem or integral formula (or another form of the residue theorem). But if you have a parametrisation of one curve, it's easy to get the parametrisation of translations of that curve, just add the appropriate constant. Here $-i + e^{it} = cos t + i((\sin t) - 1)$.

Comment: Hint: the center of your circle has now been translated to $-i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
|z-z_0| = r
$$
is the equation of a circle centered in $z_0$ with radius r. Its parametric form is
$$
z = z_0 + re^{it} = z_0 + r(\cos t + i \sin t)
$$